# php temp file upload directory - off local server

Tags: php

When uploading an image PHP stores the temp image in a local on the server.

Is it possible to change this temp location so its off the local server.

Reason: using loading balancing without sticky sessions and I don't want files to be uploaded to one server and then not avaliable on another server. Note: I don't necessaryly complete the file upload and work on the file in the one go.

Preferred temp location would be AWS S3 - also just interested to know if this is possible.

If its not possible I could make the file upload a complete process that also puts the finished file in the final location.

just interested to know if the PHP temp image/file location can be off the the local server?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount S3 bucket with [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) on your Instances which are under ELB, so that all your uploads are shared between application Servers. About /tmp, don't touch it as destination is S3 and it is shared - you don't have to worry.

If you have a lot of uploads, S3 might be bottleneck. In this case, I suggest to setup [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). Personally, I use [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.org/) because it scales well and very easy to set up. It has replication issues, but you might not use replicated volumes at all and you are fine.

Another alternatives are [Ceph](http://ceph.com/), [Sector/Sphere](http://sector.sourceforge.net/), [XtreemFS](http://www.xtreemfs.org/), [Tahoe-LAFS](https://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs),  [POHMELFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POHMELFS) and many others...

Answer (score 1):

You can directly upload a file from a client to S3 with some newer technologies as detailed in this post:

http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/direct-browser-uploading-amazon-s3-cors-fileapi-xhr2-and-signed-puts/

Otherwise, I personally would suggest using each server's `tmp` folder for exactly that-- temporary storage. After the file is on your server, you can always upload to S3, which would then be accessible across all of your load balanced servers.

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning: "With all of that in place you should now be able to upload directly to S3 using a browser that supports CORS, XHR2 and the FileAPI (pretty much everything but IE currently)."

Comment: "Pretty much everything but IE currently". The story of every web developer's career/life ;)